# Uranium of galena removed T years ago using Pb-Pb dating

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radioactivity, isotopes

So we have an equationn for Pb-Pb dating:

$$\rm \frac{\frac{207Pb}{204Pb}-\left(\frac{207Pb}{204Pb}\right)_0}{\frac{206Pb}{204Pb}-\left(\frac{206Pb}{204Pb}\right)_0}=\frac{235U}{238U}\cdot \frac{e^{\lambda_{235}t}-1}{e^{\lambda_{238}t}-1}$$

For a certain type of rock (Manitouwadge galena) it is given that the value for the LHS of the equation is $1.058$. The question is that suppose the rock had its uranium removed T years ago, use this equation to calculate T.

So at first I thought I would just fill in the values and take the current value for the uranium ratio ($\rm \frac{235U}{238U}=\frac{1}{137.88}$ and determine T. The value I got for T was $T\approx 5.32$ billion years. However, the Earth is not that old, so you run into some trouble there. Also, it is given in my book that the stone was actually isolated from lead $2.74$ billion years ago. So if "isolated from" and "removed" indicate the same things, I am confused where I go wrong.

Any help is very much appreciated!